# moving button image from first button pressed to second button pressed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, logic

I have 5X5 grids of buttons. If I press the button at position1 and then press the button at position2, I want the button image of position1 to be moved to the button at position2.  Like as shown in the example below below,  where A1 button is pressed first and then B2 button is pressed. 
Example:
[image: A1 button pressed]

**Fig: A1 button pressed**

[image: B2 button pressed]

**Fig: B2 button pressed**

So, the total process has two steps:

```
1. Prepare to move image when first button pressed
2. Move the image from first button to second button when the second button is pressed
```

I have set button tags for those 25 buttons shown in the 5X5 grid. Now I am having trouble to find out the logic to have the desired action.

What would be the logic in the these methods:

```
-(void)a1ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

}

-(void)b2ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

}
```

While the buttons have these tags:

```
A1.tag = 1;
B2.tag = 7;
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use one method for all the buttons, simple logic something like this

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn {
     if (buttonPressed) {//second press
         [initialBtn setImage:blankImage forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [btn setImage:buttonImage forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
         buttonPressed=NO;
     } else {//first press
         buttonImage=[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
         buttonPressed=YES;
         initialBtn=btn;
     }
```

In your header you would have

```
 BOOL buttonPressed;
 UIImage *buttonImage;
 UIButton *initialBtn;
```

This would also work if the user pressed the same button twice, cancelling their selection.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to obtain your goal...

You can use this method to change your button image:

```
[aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And you can manage your button image using a variable.

Then:

```
-(void)a1ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (firstButton) {
        // Get image to move from A1
        imageToMove = [A1 imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Remove image from A1
        [A1 setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = NO;
    } else {
        // Put new image to A1
        [A1 setImage:imageToMove forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = YES;
    }

}

-(void)b2ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (firstButton) {
        // Get image to move from B2
        imageToMove = [A1 imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Remove image from B2
        [B2 setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = NO;
    } else {
        // Put new image to B2
        [B2 setImage:imageToMove forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = YES;
    }
}
```

And so on...

`fistButton` is a BOOL that control if the button pressed is first or second.
`imageToMove` is a UIImage declared elsewhere that manage the image to move.

Anyway, you can use just one method for all of yours 25 buttons:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (firstButton) {
        // Get image to move from button
        imageToMove = [button imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Remove image from button
        [button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = NO;
    } else {
        // Put new image to button
        [button setImage:imageToMove forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        firstButton = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give animation need to do UIView animation that is core animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        //set animation value means the next postion where u want to move object 
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

please like it

Comment: This is good, but using these methods is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to accomplish this, add all the buttons in an array when creating the buttons and set each button a tag.Then store the tag of both pressed button.Use the previous pressed tag to read the button using [buttonarray objectAtIndex:previous.tag] and set to nil and to current tag set background image of previous button.